# More than 20 reviews in a day

Tags: support, review, rate-limiting

How is that possible?

[image]

I looked for duplicates but couldn't find any. [This question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/10003/able-to-vote-after-reaching-daily-limit) might be related.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [last suggested edit review](https://math.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/461040) by that user was for an answer they themselves wrote. Having exhausted one's review quota for the day of course does not remove the possibility to review edit suggestions for one's own posts. (I don't know for sure whether reviews for own posts count to the quota before it is exhausted, I believe they do.) In that way, also non-moderators can make more than 20 reviews of suggested edits per day.

Comment: Does it exhaust the possibility to review suggestions that you "find in nature", like voting to close outside the queue?

Comment: I'm not sure. I think they count towards the quota, but I haven't seen the code.

Comment: So we can conclude that you are not The One. Which makes sense, as your name is not Neo Anderson, I guess.

Comment: You lost me there. What's the reference to?

Comment: The Matrix? *shakes head*

Comment: I've heard of that. People say the first part wasn't so bad.

Comment: Yes, but seeing how I am able to form my own opinions, I also think the other two parts were fun. Living in a Western country for the past 16 years and not seeing the movie once is quite an achievement. You should be knighted.

Comment: @AsafKaragila [Too bad they never made any sequels.](https://xkcd.com/566/)  (Actually, I've never seen any of the movies, and I've been in a Western country for more than 16 years...)